# How to create an api controller with read/write actions with dotnet CLI

Tags: api, asp.net-core, controller

does anyone know how to create an api controller with read/write actions with dotnet CLI? I'm on vscode and mac.
Thank you

ps. ** I'm looking for a command to create an api controller with read/write actions not using ef core.**

Comment: this may helpful : https://mattmillican.com/blog/aspnetcore-controller-scaffolding

Comment: @MohammadAghazadeh Hi thank you for the post. The article is about how to create a controller with ef core using scaffolding. Im looking for a command to create a controller with read/write actions not using ef core. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, if you are using VS code, there are a lot of extension which could help you build the application more quickly.

For example, this extension: [ASP.NET Core Snippets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rahulsahay.Csharp-ASPNETCore)

You could use it to generate the controller codes.

Comment: Ok thank you I'll give it a try. Still kinda wanna know the command line lol